# What authors have tried to compare a wide variety of styles, specifically with regards to orchestration?

Tags: composition, arranging, orchestration, styles

I have never found a guide to orchestration which systematically discusses differences in the theory behind the orchestration/composition choices with regards to different typical stylistic genres, especially comparisons between genres considered "art music" (early Romantic), "pop music" (techno), and "world music" (japanese Gagaku).  What authors have come up with a guide to a wide variety of music, or a method for talking about the differences between musics which are seen as vastly different?

Comment: I’ve seen some good educational TV-Productions with Bernstein or Yehudi Menuhin.